# Android Cloudant sync query

Tags: android, cloudant

as docs say( https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md) im trying to do a query inside a list

look:

```
query.put("codigo", 4);
            result = q.find(query);
            for (DocumentRevision revision : result) {
                Log.d("QueryTest", "Test1 :" + revision.getBody().toString());
            }
```

return:

> {      "codigo":4,    "companies":[
>         {
>            "id":"b9f19d88-13c0-40e3-89de-63dc787afb4c",
>            "name":"Filial 0 1488949817178"
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"f17fb098-316e-4d33-a0f7-f5719bf9d62e",
>            "name":"Filial 1 1488949817178"
>         }    ],    "employees":[
>         {
>            "codigo":2891,
>            "id":"cc54fa37-0b64-4108-869a-1303c6176ce5",
>            "name":"Employee 0 79ed4"
>         },
>         {
>            "codigo":4642,
>            "id":"19b76bbc-82c7-4295-a385-82ac2d892458",
>            "name":"Employee 1 e1102"
>         }    ],    "id":"ef2d0ebf-50b9-4cd0-9aaf-5389bccaaa56",    "nome":"Random 4" }

so its ok

but this query doesnt work:

```
query.put("employees.codigo",  2891);
```

**first return:**

> QuerySqlTranslator: No single index contains all of 
>   [{employees.codigo={$eq=2891}}]; add index for these fields to query
>   efficiently

**after created the index:**

```
Index i = q.createJsonIndex(Arrays.<FieldSort>asList(new FieldSort("employees.codigo")), null);
```

return

> QueryExecutor: Projection fields array is empty, disabling project for
>   this query

**so i created the arraylist of fields to filter**

```
List<String> fields = Arrays.asList("codigo");
result = q.find(query, 0 , 0 , fields, null);
```

> nothing returned

**adding more one field to filter:**

```
    query.put("codigo",4)
query.put("employees.codigo",  2891);
```

> returned: Complain about index

Created another index:

```
    i = q.createJsonIndex(Arrays.<FieldSort>asList(new FieldSort("employees.codigo"), new FieldSort("codigo")), null);
```

> returned: Nothing

whats is wrong?

How can i get document by child and how can i get ONLY the children?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is unsupported, see [the doc on unsupported features](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md#unsupported-cloudant-query-features), specifically the highlighted entry:

> Arrays
>
> - **Dotted notation to index or query sub-documents in arrays.**
> - Querying for exact array match, { field: [ 1, 3, 7 ] }.
> - Querying to match a specific array element using dotted notation, { field.0: 1 }.
> - Querying using $all.
> - Querying using $elemMatch.